# Суммировать значения select (option data) в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помоги пожалуйста переделать, чтобы сумма считалась не по значениям **value** выбранных option, а по значениям **data-col**

```js
$('select').change(sum);

function sum(){
    let result=0;
    $('#sum').find('select').each(function(){
        let value = 0;
        if (typeof $(this).val() == 'object'){
          $.each($(this).val(), function(index, val) {
            value += val*1;
          });
        } else {
          value = $(this).val()
        }
        result+=value*1;
    });
    $('#itog').val(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">
  <form>
    <select id="1" name="1">
      <option data-col="5" value="1">текст</option>
      <option data-col="2" value="2">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="2" name="2">
      <option data-col="3" value="1">текст</option>
      <option data-col="4" value="2">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="3" name="3" multiple>
      <option data-col="4" value="1">текст</option>
      <option data-col="9" value="2">текст</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="itog" id="itog" value="" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('select').change(sum);

function sum() {
  let result = 0;
  $('#sum').find('select option:selected').each(function() {
    if (!isNaN($(this).data("col")))
      result += +$(this).data("col");
  });
  $('#itog').val(result);
}
sum();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sum">
  <form>
    <select id="1" name="1">
      <option data-col="5" value="1">текст</option>
      <option data-col="2" value="2">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="2" name="2">
      <option data-col="3" value="1">текст</option>
      <option data-col="4" value="2">текст</option>
    </select>
    <select id="3" name="3" multiple>
      <option data-col="4" value="1">текст</option>
      <option data-col="9" value="2">текст</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="itog" id="itog" value="" />
  </form>
</div>
```